# Which files are shared between docker container and host?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

A docker container is isolated from its host but it seems there are some files which are shared.

Is there a list of files shared between host and container by default ?

I haven't found a clear answer in Docker documentation.

I ran a classic ubuntu20.04 container on my ubuntu20.04 host using docker run:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:20.04
```

I printed the content of some files of /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/ in the container AND in the host, for instance:

```
cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_serial
```

This command prints the same result in the container AND in the host.

**I had a satisfying answer from David Maze on my [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127539/which-files-are-shared-between-docker-container-and-host) which was recently closed:**
"/sys and /proc are kernel-managed artificial filesystems, and many of the things there hit the "the kernel is shared" rule. I don't think these are shared between the host and container per se, so much as an additional instance of procfs is mounted in the container that has significant overlap with the host."

Any additional information/documentation is welcome.